# Adding collation to a counter query

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, tsqlt

How can I add COLLATION to the following query....

This Collation clause = COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS

I only need to count the St_Text field if it exactly matches.

```
SELECT St_Text, count(*) as Counter
FROM tblSTBackup
GROUP BY St_Text 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

I have tried to add the collation to the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is how it should look:

```
SELECT St_Text COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, count(*) as Counter
FROM tblSTBackup
GROUP BY St_Text COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/025e9/1)

Comment: I tried that it did not work..  Column 'tblSTBackup.St_Text' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @marc11h Did you collate the column in both the select part and the group part?

Comment: @marc11h -- should work -- check out this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/025e9/1